# Store algebird Bloom Filter with Storehaus

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming, scalding

I have a Spark job whose final output is an Algebird bloom filter, and I'd need to reuse this bloom filter in another Spark job. 
Is there a way to store this bloom filter in a kv store (eg: redis) using Twitter Storehaus and retrieve it in the other job (deserializing to an algebird bloom filter) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to do concurrent modifications to the bloomfilter, the best way would be to store the bloomfilter as a distributed bitset. Consider the key space to be an index into a partitioning of the array, and the value being the part of the array for that index.  Then you can do reads and writes with much less IO. This requires you basically re-implementing the bloom algorithm at the level or a storehaus MergeableStore.

It would be nice to have this in storehaus, but we have not actually done this. We have always used smaller bloomfilters that don't need to be distributed.